# How do you change ColdFusion 9 temp directory for uploads (CFFILE)?

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to change my CF9 Linux (Apache) servers temp directory where ColdFusion uploads files to before going to a users path. How can this be done?

Someone recommended this but CF9 errored:
*Look in the jrun.xml file under the server-inf folder. default temp: {jrun.server.rootdir}/SERVER-INF/temp*

Any help would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ian's link is for CF8 (the jRun line is the clue)

In CF9 and CF10, edit:
`cfusion/runtime/conf/server.xml`

Down near the end (probably the last complete `xml` tag) you'll find a commented out tag:

```
<Context path="/" ... ></Context>
```

You have to set the docBase (which on linux is probably `/opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/wwwroot`), then you can set the `WorkDir` to the temp folder you want.
Mine looks like so:

```
<Context path="/" docBase="/opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/wwwroot" WorkDir="/tmp/ColdFusion" ></Context>
```

It's a good idea to set the `WorkDir` to another partition, because any file management code not cleaning up after itself could eventually fill your operating system disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think the jrun.xml is probably the only way. I found this post (probably the same one you did) but aside from that I don't know of any way.

http://www.jasonholden.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/11/2/Change-Coldfusion-Temporary-Files-Location-Used-by-GetTempDirectory